# Библиотека matplotlib: построение графика для метода Ньютона

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Ребят, помогите построить график для метода Ньютона с помощью библиотеки matplotlib
Вот исходный код :

```
def f(x):
    return x ** 6 - 5 * x - 2


def fprime(x):
    return 6 * x**5 - 5


guess = 3

for val in range(1, 7):
    nextGuess = guess - f(guess) / fprime(guess)
    guess = nextGuess
    print(nextGuess)
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код в вопросе в рабочее состояние. Сейчас в нем отсутствуют отступы

Comment: В цикле `for val in range(1, 7):` вы переменную `val` не употребляете, так что удобнее писать `for __ in range(1, 7):`

Answer (score 2):

Так что у вас не получилось?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return x ** 6 - 5 * x - 2

def fprime(x):
    return 6 * x**5 - 5

guess = 3
x=list(range(1,7))
y=[]

for val in x:
    nextGuess = guess - f(guess) / fprime(guess)
    guess = nextGuess
    print(nextGuess)
    y.append(nextGuess)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: le картинка]

Comment: Всё получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: @Rich, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [проголосуйте за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь как минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) и/или [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)